# Installing ipython notebook on Linux

Tags: python, linux, ipython

I am trying to install `ipython` notebook on `Linux`. System specs are as follows: **Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server. PRODUCT VERSION 7.5**

`Anaconda` (Dec 30 2018) with `python` 3.6 has already been installed.

To install `ipython notebook`, i was doing the following:

```
$ pip install ipython
```

and

```
$ pip install jupyterlab
```

and

```
$ conda install -c conda-forge jupyterlab
```

However, i was always getting the same error as follows:

[image]

any ideas please?

Comment: Looks like you’re offline.  Try to ping `whois.com` (or any site) and see it you get a return.

Comment: And while you are at it, stop using Python 2.7

Comment: i am using the VPN connection to connect to a remote server @S3DEV

Comment: 'Network is unreachable'. Check the outside network access of the remote server.  Looks like the connection can’t get out.

Comment: @S3DEV I think the remote server is secured. Can only receive connections through a VPN access. It cannot connect to the normal internet.

Comment: Yep, there’s the issue; `pip` requires internet access - unless it’s pointed to a local file to install.  Personally, I work on an air-gapped network; so we download the Python libraries externally, security check them, then install on the air-gap.  This might be something to consider.

Comment: @S3DEV if you give me a link where i can have a good start about air-gap

Comment: TBH: Your start is as good as mine; I’d just be typing ‘python air gap' into DuckDuck, just as you might.  My only link is day to day experience; and that says ... it’s hard work.  But once you get your head around it (just by doing), it gets easier.

Answer (score 0):

Two issues:

1. Your computer is not connected to the internet.
2. Try using

   pip3

for python 3.6